# What is the best place to catch errors when reading files in python?

Tags: python, csv, error-handling

I am new to Python and struggle with the following. Users upload CSV file which I then parse. However, a lot of things can go wrong. The principal issues I have found are a) the files they upload aren't CSV files after all, or b) the files are not uploaded using UTF8 encoding (which is the default on our system).

The question is: where exactly should I check for these issues? This is my script:

```
with open(path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:

        (do stuff...)
```

I have tried adding this:

```
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
except:
    error = "There was an error..."
```

But if the user uploads a file with the wrong encoding then this is not caught. It only seems to be caught when the loop starts (for row in reader), and only for the particular row that causes trouble. Does this mean that I should have this kind of error checking inside the for statement? It seems much better to me to do it only once, not on every item, but I'm not sure what makes most sense here...

Comment: Take a look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577778-correctly-reading-csv-files-in-arbitrary-encodings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be more direct ways to catch these sorts of things with the CSV reader (I'm not sure), but when I have input files coming from other users with the potential for these sorts of errors I just parse the files manually. E.g.:

```
import sys
NumFields = 3
inf = open(path, "rU")

for line in inf:
    line = line.strip() #get rid of weird end-of-line characters from bad encoding
    ls = line.split(",")
    if len(ls) != NumFields:
         ls = line.split("\t") ##if you can't get the number of fields with comma split, try tab
         if len(ls) != NumFields:
             sys.exit(1)
    print ls
```